# Selenium -Core Java Error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();  
    wd.get("https://www.wordpress.com/");  
}
```

There are no compile time errors with this but as soon as Mozilla opens, it says **"This connection is untrusted"**. I wish to open the url that I've specified in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox driver like this -

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile","your custom firefox profile name");
String browserProfile = stem.getProperty("webdriver.firefox.profile");
FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile(browserProfile); 
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates (true); 
webdriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: With this code, I get a run time error as follows:-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at selePackage.Demo.main(Demo.java:33)

Comment: which line is line 33?

Comment: Line 33 is:  myProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

Comment: Now, It's giving errors on "stem" and "webdriver" variables